# Différence entre la prorogation et la prolongation dans le contexte des marchés financiers

Tags: terminologie, différence, jargon

Dans le jargon des marchés financiers, il est courant d'entendre les termes "prorogation" et "prolongation" en relation avec la soumission d'offres ou d'enchères. Cependant, la distinction précise entre ces deux termes n'est pas toujours évidente.

1. Pourriez-vous clarifier la différence entre la prorogation et la prolongation dans le contexte des marchés financiers ?
2. Quand dit-on qu'une soumission a été "prorogée" et quand dit-on qu'elle a été "prolongée" ?
3. Existe-t-il des implications spécifiques associées à chacun de ces termes dans ce contexte ?

Merci d'avance

Comment: **Proroger** : *Envoyer à une date ultérieure, accorder un délai : le délai a été prorogé* →  la date des enchères ou de soumission des devis a été déplacée. — **Prolonger** : *Faire aller au-delà d'une limite antérieurement fixée ; faire, durer plus longtemps.* → La séance a été prolongée, donc la période pour soumettre des devis ou de préparer les enchères a été augmentée. — *Sources* : Le petit Robert.

Comment: En l'absence de définition spécifique à la finance dans les dictionnaires FR et si tu connais les termes équivalents en anglais, je dirais -> https://quant.stackexchange.com/. Parce que tomber sur un spécialiste d'un domaine de niche qui se balade sur french.stackexchange est rare (déjà que les professionnels de la langue ou du milieu littéraire n'y courent pas les rues...)

Comment: La prorogation correspond à un report à une date ultérieure tandis que la prolongation correspond à l'ajout d'un délai supplémantaire à la durée initialement prévue pour réaliser une prestation ou livrer une marchandiser. [source](https://www.e-affacturage.fr/definition/prorogation.html)

Comment: @source je pense que votre réponse est la plus courte et plus concise, merci

Comment: Merci aux autres aussi, bien sûr!